# Printing result of Ping in Yes or No form in a Text File

Tags: batch, ping

I want to print the result of ping in a Yes or No form. If we are getting reply than print Yes in a file or else No.

[test.txt=>Input File  hassan1.txt=>Output File ]

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
echo %%a
ping %%a>>C:\Users\dell\Desktop\hassan1.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: In Windows `ping` returns 0 on success, or 1 on failure (in Linux it always returns 0).

Comment: @AFH: the linux version does return 0, 1 or 2 accordingly.

Comment: @Codism - Not on Ubuntu. I'm sure it ought to return non-zero on an error, but I always get zero back, whether the network is down or the site doesn't exist. I unjustly made the assumption that such a basic utility would be common to most distributions. Mea culpa.

Comment: @AFH: that's strange. I just tried on both Ubuntu 15.04 and Debian 8. The exit code did reflect the results as expected. Maybe you have a highly customized version?

Comment: @Codism - What a dumbo I am. I set an alias to call a script to add some default parameters and forgot I was using it! I blame it on seasonal excess. You are absolutely right on all counts.

Answer (score 1):

One option, using IF:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQ 0 (
  echo Yes
) ELSE (
  echo No
)
```

Another option, using operators:

```
(ping 8.8.8.8 && echo "Yes") || echo "No"
```